# Websphere MQ 7.0.1-14 - able to add missing ssl cipher suites?

Tags: ssl, cipher, ibm-mq

I have to connect to a MQ 9 QMGR, which does not allow the available Cipher Suites I can choose from in MQ Explorer that is part of my 7.0.1-14 installation (Linux x86_64).

Can I add the needed Cipher Suites without upgrading to a newer MQ Version?

An acceptable Cipher Suite would be "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256" for example.

Comment: UPDATE: es far as i can see, i need to install GSKit 8, which will include the new Ciphers. Problem ist, to download GSKit 8, i need to have an IBM support agreement, which i dont have. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQ Explorer is a Java based application so does not rely on the GSKit version but instead on Java's underlying JSSE implementation.

In general a non-java applications using MQ v7.0.1.14 could utilize TLS1.2 cipherspecs if they have installed GSKit 8 and have specified the `AltGSKit=YES` setting in the `SSL` stanza of the `mqclient.ini`, this does not apply however to Java applications like MQ Explorer.

Supporting this is the following info in APAR **[IT00326: WMQ V7.X EXPLORER IS NOT ABLE TO CONFIGURE A CIPHER SPECIFICATION SUPPORTED BY GSKIT V8 FOR A V7.0.1 QUEUE MANAGER](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT00326)** talking about using MQ Explorer to configure channels on a 7.0.1.4 or later queue manager that has the `AltGSKit=YES` setting in place in the `SSL` stanza of the `qm.ini`.  (bolded the key info below):

> The WebSphere MQ Explorer has been updated to allow the configuration
>   of the following CipherSpecs on a channel definition when connected to
>   a version 7.0.1 queue manager:
>
> `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256`
>   `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`
>   `TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256`
>
> These CipherSpecs require GSKit 8 to be configured on the queue
>   manager. Attempting to set these CipherSpecs for a channel definition
>   on a version 7.0.1 queue manager which is using GSKit 7 will cause MQ
>   Explorer to display an AMQ4126 error.
>
> It should be noted that **WebSphere MQ Explorer version 7.0.1 does not
>   support the use of these three CipherSpecs for its communications with
>   the queue manager over a ServerConnection channel.**

The IBM MQ Classes for Java does not support SHA2 cipherspecs until MQ v7.1.

I would recommend you download the standalone MQ v9.1 Explorer SupportPac, you can find it here: [MS0T: IBM MQ Explorer](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24021041).

The versions listed below are all End of Support at this time and v8 is going to be end of support on April 30th 2020:

```
V7.0 EOS: September 30 2015
V7.1 EOS: April     30 2017
V7.5 EOS: April     30 2018
V8.0 EOS: April     30 2020
```